# Whats the proper logic and way to save JSON data that has a nested array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I figured this out the answer is below

So say I have something like this JSON POST coming in:

```
{
  "contact":{
      "first_name": "Bill",
      "last_name": "Clinton",
      "phone_numbers":[
          {
            "name": "blah", 
            "number": "555-555-5555" 
           },
           {
           "name": "blah2", 
           "number": "555-555-5555" 
           }
      ]
  }
}
```

Forgive me for the crappy formatting of the JSON.
Anyway, I want to save this into my DB. The Rails controller will be taking care of this. Now
I am a bit tired but I am unsure how to handle this since there is a nested array.
Please Help.

So I have a contacts table which a has a phone_number_id field. phone_number table has name and number fields

Current attempt until I realized I have a nested array:

```
    @phone_number = Phone_Number.new
    @phone_number.contact_id = @contact.id
    @phone_number.name       = @params[:phone_number_name]
```

Comment: Love a good down-vote for no reason.... Could Always just give me a reason as to why so I can change my question. But the helpful downvote is always great.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what tables/objects you have. I assume there is a Contact object. Is there a PhoneNumber object too? Is it connected in a has_many relationship with Contact?  (There are ways to set up things (maybe it was a gem) to map this stuff. Don't remember off the top of my head but could look through old projects for it.)

Comment: @TooTiredToDrink did not downvote but you know you have to show an attempt at least. Add what you try I will counter vote

Comment: @meda, right see I added my attempt, but how is that useful? I realized I had a nested array no clear clue how to do it. I thank you but I just didn't see how that is useful.

Comment: It shows that you tried something and can be helpful, look at [the comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417080/whats-the-proper-logic-and-way-to-save-json-data-that-has-a-nested-array?noredirect=1#comment41481373_26417080) Im just giving you tips to ask better question

Answer (score 0):

Here is The solution I came up with

```
    if @contact.save
      @params[:phone_numbers].each do |counter|
        @phone            = PhoneNumber.new
        @phone.contact_id = @contact.id
        @phone.name       = counter[:name]
        @phone.number     = counter[:number]
        @phone.save
      end
```